Sum and integral of a series of complex functions
I'm working on this exercise but I don't know if all my passages are legit.

Let $z\in\mathbb Z\setminus \{ \pm n:n\in\mathbb N \}$ and let
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{n(iz-\pi)}}{z^2-n^2}$$


Determine the set $A$ of pointwise convergence
Show that the the sum $S$ is holomorphic on the interior of $A$
Compute $\int_{\Gamma} S(z)dz$ where $\Gamma = \{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z-1-i|=2\}$

Let us defined $f_n(z) = \frac{e^{n(iz-\pi)}}{z^2-n^2}$. I started by considering that the series converges pointwise if $\Im(z)\geq -\pi$ because otherwise $f_n(z)\rightarrow +\infty$ if $n\rightarrow +\infty$.
Hence $A= \{ z\in \mathbb C \setminus \{ \pm n:n\in\mathbb N \}: \Im(z)\geq -\pi\}$.
In order to show 2. I used the weierstrass M-test on $\Omega \subset A$ (it does not converge on $A$ itself am I right? I need an open set) to show that uniformly converges. In fact if we consider a compact subset of $A$
\begin{equation}
\left|\frac{e^{n(iz-\pi)}}{z^2-n^2}\right|=\frac{e^{-(\Im(z)+\pi)n}}{|z^2-n^2|}\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon}e^{-\epsilon n}.
\end{equation} where $|z^2-n^2|\geq \epsilon$ and $\Im(z)\geq -\pi+\epsilon$.
Hence the series uniformly converges to an holomorphic function $S(z)$.
But now how can I compute the integral? My guess is that I have to switch the integral sign with the series one and maybe use the Residue theorem on every $f_n$ but am I allowed to switch integral and sum signs? Is that Fubini-Tonelli and Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem but in complex variables?
Any Hint?

Your $A$ contains, for instance, $z=-4\mathrm{i}$ for which the series diverges. Also your series of estimates is incorrect. Take $z = n\sqrt {1+ \frac{{\rm 1}}{{\rm 2}}{\rm e}^{ - \pi n} }$.

There were a typo in the set $A$, I tried to correct it but I still don't know if it is correct.

@Gary true that estimate is not so how can I procede?

Hint: $$
\left| {\frac{{{\rm e}^{n({\rm i}z - \pi )} }}{{z^2  - n^2 }}} \right| = \frac{{{\rm e}^{ - ({\mathop{\rm Im}\nolimits} (z) + \pi )n} }}{{\left| {z^2  - n^2 } \right|}} \le \frac{1}{\varepsilon }{\rm e}^{ - \varepsilon n} ,
$$ provided $\left| {z^2  - n^2 } \right| \ge \varepsilon$ and ${\mathop{\rm Im}\nolimits} (z) \ge  - \pi  + \varepsilon$.

@Gary ok thank you so much! I'll try to revisit the estimate. Can you give me an hint about the integral? Is my guess correct?

Your estimates still do not make sense. $\mathrm{i}\operatorname{Im}(z)$ is a non-real complex number if $\operatorname{Im}(z)\ne 0$, hence you cannot use it in an upper bound.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I thought about a possible solution to the integral.
We know that S(z) is holomorphic in subsets of $A$ hence is holomorphic also in $\{|z-1-i|<2+\delta\}\setminus\{1\}$.
Since the series is totally convergent we can use Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem to show that
\begin{equation}
\int_{\Gamma} S(z)dz = \int_{\Gamma} \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{n(iz-\pi)}}{z^2-n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \int_{\Gamma} \frac{e^{n(iz-\pi)}}{z^2-n^2}
\end{equation}
Since $\Gamma=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z-1-i|=2\}$ for every $n\neq 1,2$ we have that $f_n$ is holomorphic inside $\Gamma$ and its singularities does not lie on or inside $\Gamma$, hence the integral is 0.
So we are left with
\begin{equation}
\int_{\Gamma} S(z)dz = \int_{\Gamma} f_1(z)dz + \int_{\Gamma} f_2(z)dz
\end{equation}

$\left| { \pm 1 - {\rm i}} \right| = \sqrt 2  \ne 2$, so $0$ and $2$ do not lie on $\Gamma$.

Furthermore, the sum starts at $n=1$, and hence there is no $f_0$.

Perfect THANK YOU :)
